# Примеры использования указателей

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Пытаюсь разобраться в указателях. Увидел такие примеры, но не нашёл что они делают. Зачем используются эти варианты?

1. `*int *pa`;
2. `int *(*pa)`;

Comment: 1 - ошибка компиляции. 2- тоже что и `int ** pa;`

Comment: Где увидели? Недостаточно контекста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае будет ошибка компиляции.
Второму примеру аналогична вот эта запись.

```
int ** pa;
```

то есть так называемый "Указатель на указатель на int". Работает он по принципу обычного указателя, то есть вы можете его разыименовать для получения значения, которое храниться по данному адресу. А поскольку в "первой звездочке" храниться еще один указатель, то при разыименовании Вы получите адрес переменной

```
int pa
```

Для получения значения из "Указателя на указатель", его нужно разыменовать дважды вот так.

```
int a = 5;
int *pa = &a;
std:cout << *pa;
```

Обратите внимание, что инициализировать указатель на указатель в одну строку нельзя.

```
//Нельзя вот так
int a = 5;
**pa = &&a;
```

Это связано с тем, что оператор & требует в качестве значения I-value, но в этом случае значение r-value.

Однако если поддерживается С++11 можно разыменовать указатель на указатель через null

```
 int **pa = nullptr;
```

В первом и втором случае выведется число 5.